# Undefined reference to symbol ao compilar programa em C++

Tags: c++, gcc

Estou testando a biblioteca curlPP e escrevi o seguinte programa:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace curlpp::options;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   curlpp::Cleanup myCleanup;
   std::cout << curlpp::options::Url("http://wikipedia.org");
   std::ostringstream os;
   os << curlpp::options::Url("http://wikipedia.org");
   return 0;
}
```

E compilando com o seguinte comando:

```
g++ -o http_get httpreq.cpp -lcurlpp
```

No entanto, recebo:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccSQpqLj.o: undefined reference to symbol     'curl_easy_setopt@@CURL_GNUTLS_3'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Alguma ideia de como resolver o problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incluir a biblioteca `curlPP` não é suficiente, tens que compilar o teu programa usando também a biblioteca `Curl`.

Tenta assim:

```
g++ -lcurlpp -lcurl -o http_get httpreq.cpp
```

Comment: Obrigado! Do jeito que está ai não compilou, mas troquei as flags do linker de lugar, ficando `g++ -o http_get httpreq.cpp -lcurlpp -lcurl ` e funcionou.

Comment: Estranho, eu compilo pela ordem que tenho  na resposta e funciona bem. De qualquer das formas, ainda bem que funcionou!